# How to create an alert for only long entry in a strategy in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I have a strategy that creates the long entry, long exit, short entry, and short exit. And for all that, I want to automate my strategy with Weebhook and for that, I have to create separate alerts. but I am unable to create a separate alert, my alert is triggered on every action of strategy.

This is my code of strategy, How could I create separate alerts for every action (long entry, long exit, short entry, and short exit) in Tradingview?